# store DOM-elements using objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, object

I'm making a game where I want to store the enemies as an object before loading them into the game.

```
var that = this;
this.enemies = {
    that.redCar : document.getElementById('red'),   
    that.sportsCar : document.getElementById('sport')
}
```

But this gives me a syntax error.  I thought `that.redCar : document.getElementById('red')` in an object would be equal to `that.redCar = document.getElementById('red')` outside of one.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say `this.enemies = { ... }`, you are declaring an Object literal that is inside of `this`, i.e.:

```
this
  enemies
    redCar: ...
    sportsCar: ...
```

It doesn't make sense to say `that.redCar = ...`, because you are already inside `enemies`. If you want to access it like

```
this.enemies.redCar
```

then you can just do this:

```
this.enemies = {
    redCar : document.getElementById('red'),   
    sportsCar : document.getElementById('sport')
}
```

And if you want to access it like

```
this.redCar
```

then don't use `enemies` at all, and just do

```
this.redCar = document.getElementById('red'),   
this.sportsCar = document.getElementById('sport')
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to believe that it is necessary to declare the `this` keyword when assigning properties to a JavaScript object.

While this may be true when defining an object's constructor, like so...

```
function MyClass() {
    this.color = "blue";
}
var myObj = new MyClass();
```

...right now, this is *not* the case.

When you use the "object literal" syntax (`var myObj = { /*properties...*/ };`), `this` isn't required; in fact, it isn't allowed.

Here's how you should assign those properties:

```
this.enemies = {
    redCar: document.getElementById('red'),   
    sportsCar: document.getElementById('sport')
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `string` as an object key, thus `that.redCar` is illegal.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a different function scope than the one that you listed in your code, there is no need to use `this`. Just declare an object literal:

```
enemies = {
    redCar : document.getElementById('red'),   
    sportsCar : document.getElementById('sport')
}

// example reference
enemies.redCar.className += " active";
```

Also, be careful with `this`. Unless you are using `this` within the scope of a function, you are referring to the window object. Unless you are declaring the above code within a function scope that you have not stated, `this` refers to the global object.

Answer (score -1):

I think is better to declare the variable that as an object, no? You better try with:

```
var that = new Object();
```

Instead of:

```
var that = this;
```

Or what is the declaration of this?

Comment: that = this is just a reference to this so I can use it in other part of a class I have. You are just seeing a tiny part of the code

Comment: Take in consideration the answer of Doorknoob, saying to use this inside the enemies to acces of the properties

Comment: There is dynamic type-checking. A variable does not have a specific type. It has a value, and the value has a type. `this` is a built-in, usually a reference to an object. `{}` (object initialiser) evaluates to a reference to a new `Object` instance, the same as `new Object()`.